# How to derive an estimator for the parameter of a continuous uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, estimation, uniform-distribution, estimators

$X_1, X_2,\dots.,X_n$ are i.i.d. random variates drawn from a continuous uniform distribution over $[0,\theta].$ The sufficient statistic is denoted $\max$.

I want an estimator $e$ of $\theta$ that estimates $\theta$ in such a way that $E_{\theta}\left| \theta -e\right|$ is minimal.

My attempt 1: The density for $\max$ given some fixed $\theta$  turns out to be:

$$L=n \left(\max/\theta\right)^{n-1}/\theta\quad,\quad 0<\max<\theta$$

Now the mean that must be minimal is found:
$$E_{\theta}\left| \theta -e\right|=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left| \theta -\max\cdot A\right|\cdot L\ d\max =\\
\left(2 A^{-n}+A n-n-1\right)\theta/(1+n)$$

Solving $\frac{d}{dA}E_{\theta}\left| \theta -\max\cdot A\right| = 0$ yields $A = 2^{1/(1 + n)}$. I think $e=2^{1/(1 + n)}\cdot\max$ is what I'm looking for.

My attempt 2: Since $\max$ is in fact known, I think $L$ can be interpreted as some kind of likelyhood function revealing gods bias during the choice of $\theta$. From that reason I think the following should be true
$$E_{\theta}\left| \theta -e\right|\propto\int_{\max}^{\infty}\left| \theta -e\right|\cdot L\ d\theta =\\
\frac{n \left(2\max ^n \text{e}^{2-n}-\max ^2 (n-1)+\max  (n-2) \text{e}\right)}{\max  \left(n^2-3 n+2\right)}$$

Now solving $\frac{d}{de}E_{\theta}\left| \theta -e\right| = 0$ yields $e=2^{1/(n - 1)}\cdot\max$, which is quite different.

What is wrong and how should I, in general, go on about deriving an estimator that minimizes some mean.

Comment: If you can see that the likelihood function is proportional to $1/\theta^n$, for $\theta\ge\max\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, you're done.